# Pinning a Java application to the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: java, windows-7, java-native-interface, launch4j, taskbar

I use Launch4j as a wrapper for my Java application under Windows 7, which, to my understanding, in essence forks an instance of `javaw.exe` that in turn interprets the Java code. As a result, when attempting to pin my application to the task bar, Windows instead pins `javaw.exe`. Without the required command line, my application will then not run.

[image: Result of pinning a Launch4j application to the taskbar]

As you can see, Windows also does not realize that Java is the host application: the application itself is described as "Java(TM) Platform SE binary".

I have tried altering the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\javaw.exe` to add the value `IsHostApp`. This alters the behavior by disabling pinning of my application altogether; clearly not what I want.

[image: Result of specifying javaw.exe as a host application]

After reading about [how Windows interprets instances of a single application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28VS.85%29.aspx) (and [a phenomenon discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330939/pinning-advertised-shortcuts-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-7)), I became interested in embedding a Application User Model ID (AppUserModelID) into my Java application.

I believe that I can resolve this by passing a unique `AppUserModelID` to Windows. There is a `shell32` method for this, [`SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378422%28VS.85%29.aspx). Following Gregory Pakosz suggestion, I implemented it in an attempt to have my application recognized as a separate instance of `javaw.exe`:

```
NativeLibrary lib;
try {
    lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance("shell32");
} catch (Error e) {
    Logger.out.error("Could not load Shell32 library.");
    return;
}
Object[] args = { "Vendor.MyJavaApplication" };
String functionName = "SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID";
try {
    Function function = lib.getFunction(functionName);
    int ret = function.invokeInt(args);
    if (ret != 0) {
        Logger.out.error(function.getName() + " returned error code "
                + ret + ".");
    }
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    Logger.out.error(functionName + " was not found in "
            + lib.getFile().getName() + ".");
    // Function not supported
}
```

This appears to have no effect, but the function returns without error. Diagnosing why is something of a mystery to me. Any suggestions?

### Working implementation

The final implementation that worked is [the answer to my follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907735/using-jna-to-get-set-application-identifier) concerning how to pass the `AppID` using JNA.

I had awarded the bounty to Gregory Pakosz' brilliant answer for JNI that set me on the right track.

For reference, I believe using this technique opens the possibility of using any of the APIs discussed [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx) in a Java application.

Comment: For JSmooth. Use gimp to convert your .ico to a .png if you want.

Comment: try to use the `String.getBytes("UTF-16");` method

Comment: Someone opened a feature request for native support in launch4j: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3483933&group_id=95944&atid=613103 Help getting this feature in the next 3.1 release!

Comment: The images linked in your question seem to have expired. Do you have copies saved that you could reupload and edit in?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't. They depicted (1) that right-clicking on the app and pinning it created a non-executable link to `javaw.exe`, not my app, and (2) after seeing the registry key right-clicking disallowed pinning altogether.

Comment: I've recovered those missing images thanks to the Wayback Machine!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't have Windows 7 but here is something that might get you started:

On the Java side:

```
package com.stackoverflow.homework;

public class MyApplication
{
  static native boolean setAppUserModelID();

  static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("MyApplicationJNI");
    setAppUserModelID();
  }
}
```

And on the native side, in the source code of the `MyApplicationJNI.dll library:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_stackoverflow_homework_MyApplication_setAppUserModelID(JNIEnv* env)
{
  LPCWSTR id = L"com.stackoverflow.homework.MyApplication";
  HRESULT hr = SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(id);

  return hr == S_OK;
}
```

Your question explicitly asked for a JNI solution. However, since your application doesn't need any other native method, [jna](https://github.com/twall/jna/) is another solution which will save you from writing native code just for the sake of forwarding to the windows api. If you decide to go jna, pay attention to the fact that `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()` is expecting a UTF-16 string.

When it works in your sandbox, the next step is to add operating system detection in your application as `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()` is obviously only available in Windows 7:

- you may do that from the Java side by checking that `System.getProperty("os.name");` returns `"Windows 7"`.
- if you build from the little JNI snippet I gave, you can enhance it by dynamically loading the `shell32.dll` library using [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) then getting back the `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` function pointer using [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx). If `GetProcAddress` returns `NULL`, it means the symbol is not present in `shell32` hence it's not Windows 7.

EDIT: [JNA Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907735/using-jna-to-get-set-application-identifier/1928830#1928830).

References:

- [The JNI book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html) for more JNI examples
- [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna/)

Comment: This looks very good! There was no specific reason I was going for JNI. I have some Mac-specific methods using JNI, but I will definitely take your suggestion into consideration.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know whether you were familiar with JNI or not

Comment: In retrospect, I can only get the JNI methods specifically written for Mac compiled on a Mac. I've been looking into JNA, and it looks much more intuitive. I haven't actually tried it yet, but as the bounty is about to expire, I'm going to go ahead and award the points.

Comment: I've edited my question with my JNA implementation. This appears to have no effect; does this have something to do with UTF-16? If so, how do I pass a String in this encoding?

Comment: My previous questions concerning string encoding were answered [in this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907735/using-jna-to-get-set-application-identifier).

Comment: Using `System.getProperty("os.name")` might not be very future-proof. Using `System.getProperty("os.version")` returns `"6.1"` for me on Windows 7 and `"3.8.4-102.fc17.x86_64"` on Fedora 17, so you might be able to check that `System.getProperty("os.name")` contains `"Windows"` and then convert the `os.version` property to a double to compare against 6.1.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Java library providing the new Windows 7 features for Java. It's called [J7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/) by [Strix Code](http://www.strixcode.com). Applications using it can be properly pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar. You can also create your own jump lists, etc.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using proprietary libraries. Nevertheless, it seems to encompass everything that you might possibly want to integrate from Java in Windows 7. Looks good!

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). I use always this one. In JSmooth is there an option under `Skeleton` by `Windowed Wrapper` called

> Lauch java app in exe process

See on this image.

[image: JSmooth]
<sub>(source: [andrels.com](https://www.andrels.com/wp-pt_BR/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/1.jpg))</sub>

Also command line arguments can be passed.
I think this can be a solution for you.

Martijn

Comment: I've heard of this wrapper in the past. I've given it a swing, but I can't get it to do anything as it regularly hangs. Whenever I select the "Skeleton" tab, I cannot select another tab. If I visit that tab last, and press compile, it remains hanging on "Loading icon...". I'm using Windows 7, but the same happens using Vista compatibility mode. It doesn't start at all for compatibility under previous versions of Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: After some fiddling I got a version compiled. It seems selecting an icon causes the problems described in my previous comment. If I select **Launch the app in the exe process** under the **Skeleton** tab, pinning works as expected. This doesn't really answer my question of embedding an `AppID`, but it circumvents the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I can only load non-ICO images for the icon. Regardless, when pinning the application, the RelaunchIconResource (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391573(VS.85).aspx) is shown as Window's default application icon. Using Resource Hacker, I can see that this icon is contained within the EXE under Icon Group A2. Replacing it is reflected in the pinned application, but this is hardly a solution.

Comment: Concerning the above suggestion to use a single PNG opposed to an ICO: this is not an option for my project, I'm afraid, as the O/S-dependent distribution really requires different resolution application icons. I appreciate this answer, but it doesn't address the question at hand and switching to a different wrapper is not a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented access to the SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID method using JNA and it works quite well when used as the MSDN documentation suggests. I've never used the JNA api in the way you have in your code snippet. My implementation follows the [typical JNA usage](https://github.com/twall/jna/#getting_started) instead.

First the Shell32 interface definition:

```
interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    int SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( WString appID );

}
```

Then using JNA to load Shell32 and call the function:

```
final Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
    {
       put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
       put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
    }
};
Shell32 shell32 = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("shell32", Shell32.class,
           WIN32API_OPTIONS);
WString wAppId = new WString( "Vendor.MyJavaApplication" );
shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( wAppId );
```

Many of the API's in the last article you mentioned make use of Windows COM which is quite difficult to use directly with JNA. I have had some success creating a custom DLL to call these API's (eg. using the SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow to set a different app ID for a submodule window) which I then use JNA to access at runtime.

Comment: This is very much in line with Gregory Pakosz's answer to my follow-up question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907735/using-jna-to-get-set-application-identifier). I'm very curious about the "custom DLL" you speak of. This is something made in C#, I presume? Can you give any more information?

Comment: No I chose to make a custom DLL in C which is very easy to call with JNA. So far I have only implemented a SetWindowAppId function in the C DLL which calls SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow and is then able manipulate the resulting COM interfaces to set the window's appID (exactly as the various Microsoft examples show.) I am also planning on implementing a few functions for manipulating my application's Jump Lists but I haven't got there yet. Quite conveniently JNA provides API in its Native class for retrieving a Java Window's handle/pointer which makes this approach possible.

Comment: @The_Fire: Can You provide the SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow code?

Comment: @The_Fire: Ok, I implemented it by myself - wasn't that difficult. :)

Answer (score 3):

SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID (or SetAppID()) would in fact do what you're trying to do.  However, it might be easier to modify your installer to set the AppUserModel.ID property on your shortcut - quoting from the [Application User Model ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459(VS.85).aspx) document mentioned above:

> In the [System.AppUserModel.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391569(VS.85).aspx) property of the application's shortcut file. A shortcut (as an IShellLink, CLSID_ShellLink, or a .lnk file) supports properties through IPropertyStore and other property-setting mechanisms used throughout the Shell. This allows the taskbar to identify the proper shortcut to pin and ensures that windows belonging to the process are appropriately associated with that taskbar button. 
>   Note: The System.AppUserModel.ID property should be applied to a shortcut when that shortcut is created. When using the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) to install the application, the [MsiShortcutProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408039(VS.85).aspx) table allows the AppUserModelID to be applied to the shortcut when it is created during installation.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, thanks. I have actually looked into this (I use Inno Setup, which claims to include the `System.AppUserModel.ID` in shortcuts. After some experimentation I couldn't in fact reproduce the result. Furthermore, even if this worked, a user would end up confused when making a shortcut by hand. I would much rather prefer to encapsulate an `AppUserModelID` into my Java application. Would this be possible via JNI?

Answer (score 1):

The latest `jna-platform` library now includes JNA bindings for `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/680

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine without any ID settings.
There is an option in Launch4J if you are using it and you say you do then...

You can change the header to JNI Gui and then wrap it around the jar with the JRE.
The good thing is that it runs .exe in the process now instead on running javaw.exe with your jar. It probably does it under the hood (not sure).
Also I have noticed also that it takes around 40-50% less CPU resource which is even better!

And the pinning works fine and all that window features are enabled.

I hope it helps to someone as I spent nearly 2 days trying to solve that issue with my undecorated javafx app.

Comment: This option is not possible if you need a 64-bit version of javaw.exe.  There is a project called Launch5J which might work for 64-bit versions, though it didn't work for me.