# How to make .exe file for izpack installer .jar file

Tags: java, jar, installation, exe, izpack

I make an installer with **izpack**. Its in .jar file. I want to make it in .exe file in order to distribute it. How can I do it in an easy way?

Answer (score 8):

Andrew always likes to promote **Java Web Start** technology from the start :) It is a nice tech. But, you also need to learn the technical parts first before you can start tinkering with it.

Otherwise, you are left with the old-style EXE distribution model as follows...

I am not familiar with **Izpack** anyway. But, there are similar separate tools to achieve the combined result as to what **izPack** can do. My favorite EXE creation and installer tools are **Launch4J** + **InnoSetup** + **Ant task** running from **Eclipse IDE**.

**Launch4J** is a Java app launcher.
**InnoSetup** is an installation creator
**Ant task** helps developers on build and integration steps.

*How to use Launch4J + InnoSetup + Ant build task + Eclipse IDE*:
http://www.eteks.com/tips/tipCreationExe.html (in French - use Google translate)

When you are thinking of distributing a desktop-based Windows EXE file for a Java app, you also need to think about the target environment. It is fine when you are targeting Windows XP or lesser version. But, it will start to be a major frustration when you want to make it work properly under Windows Vista and Windows 7.

It is best not to store application configurations, temporary files, etc. that require saving into`%ProgramFiles%` under Windows Vista/Windows 7 as it now becomes a **read-only** folder. Use user's profile folder for such purpose.

Of course, you can bypass it by running your app with "Run as Administrator" but it involves the following setup:

> Windows Vista and Windows 7 have
>   introduced a strict user access policy
>   through the User Access Control (UAC)
>   prompt feature. The software
>   installation must be done using a user
>   account under Administrators group.
>   All folders under the default Windows’
>   system `Program Files` are set to
>   read-only and it may cause a problem
>   to non-administrator user accounts
>   when trying to save something in it. To run Java app using a
>   non-administrator user account, the
>   application properties must be set to
>   enable `Run as administrator`. A
>   shortcut shall be created in the
>   Desktop and be set to enable `Run as
>   administrator` as well.

How to solve the following issues:

*(1) Issue with `AppUserModelID` Java support in Windows Vista/Windows 7 needs the following solution:*
[Launch4j, NSIS, and duplicate pinned Windows 7 taskbar icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438651/launch4j-nsis-and-duplicate-pinned-windows-7-taskbar-icons/5439511#5439511)

*(2) Issue with `Run as Administrator` for a Java app needs the following solution:*
[Request admin privileges for Java app on Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258728/request-admin-privileges-for-java-app-on-windows-vista)

Other than those, you also need to check on `%ProgramFiles%` when running under 64-bit Windows version. The path is not the same between 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Windows. Under 64-bit Windows, all 32-bit apps will go into `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

So, be careful when using the hard-coded file path value to your Java app's folder and sub-folders that are installed in `%ProgramFiles%`. It is better to set up a `Windows environment variable` which can be generated by **InnoSetup** in the following ISS file snippet. Use Java `System.getenv("MYAPP_HOME")` to retrieve the variable:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MYAPP_HOME"; ValueData: "{app}\"

[Tasks]
Name: modifypath; Description:"Add application directory to your environmental path"; Flags: unchecked

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.EXE"; Parameters: """{app}""\"; WorkingDir: "{app}\"; Description: "Run MyApp"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent

[Code]

const
    ModPathName = 'modifypath';
    ModPathType = 'system';

function ModPathDir(): TArrayOfString;
begin
    setArrayLength(Result, 1)
    Result[0] := ExpandConstant('{app}');
end;
#include "modpath.iss"
```

Experiment and enjoy!

Comment: "Java Web Start" can be a nice solution but I want to create .exe file from Izpack installer .jar file.

Comment: Did you know about "izpack2exe"?

Answer (score 0):

If the app. has a GUI and you can distribute from a web site, [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) offers the best solution.  JWS works for all platforms that support Java, and is supported by Oracle.

(I hear that .Net works well for 'Windows only' solutions.)

Comment: My app has no GUI. "Java Web Start" can be a nice solution but I want to create .exe file from Izpack installer .jar file.

Comment: Did you know about "izpack2exe"?

Answer (score 0):

[winrun4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) is very easy to use, my only issue with it is that unless you are distributing with an embedded JVM you'll probably have to provide both a 64bit and a 32bit download.