# What is the best way to deploy a Java with JOGL application (especially with regards to Windows 7 64 bit)?

Tags: java, deployment, 64-bit, jogl, launcher

I have a JOGL application that I want to distribute.  No problems in Linux or Mac (other than -version:1.6 doesn't seem to work on Linux or Mac).  However, on Windows 7 64 bit, I have seen many different configurations of Java.  I need Java 1.6 and it must be the 64 bit version if the computer is 64 bits because of the JOGL native binaries.

So, what is the best way to deploy a Java with JOGL application?  Many of my customers do not have reliable internet access so the web deployments do not work for me.

What I have tried:

I have created an installer with NSIS that can find the 1.6 64 bit Java.  The problem is, the installation may change.  So I believe I should make a launcher that detects the location on startup.  Relying on the path to be set up properly hasn't worked in 2 out of 5 computers I have checked so far.

Comment: Maybe, you can store the installation path (set by the user or set default by installer) in an OS environment variable. You can use the environment variable  in your Java program by using `System.getenv()`. In the given hyper-link, the instruction uses `InnoSetup` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646813/how-to-make-exe-file-for-izpack-installer-jar-file/5647255#5647255

Answer (score 2):

check out this helper on "jogl-deployment":  http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/deployment/JOGL-DEPLOYMENT.html

(covers jws-jnlp, libraries by platform, etc)

FYI: in-so-far as you still want more, after a few tries, the magic google query that inst-yeilded this helper page was:     jogl jar with native libraries

1 other to skim if your question not answered: http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/FAQ