# jar to exe convert problem

Tags: java, exe

hi i converted my jar file into an exe using jsmooth but when i install it, it shows an error like java not found.
Please help me, how can I add the jre to my exe wrapper so this problem is solved.

Comment: I am not so clear what you mean by `when I install it`. What is it: JSmooth or the EXE? I am not familiar with **JSmooth**, so I suggest you to try  **Launch4J** which does the same thing plus JRE bundle/download support. In that case, you can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646813/how-to-make-exe-file-for-izpack-installer-jar-file/5647255#5647255

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to get the java installation to run your application, where it might be searching in JAVA_HOME, So if the JAVA_HOME is not set in the machine where you installing your application then try to install the java and set the JAVA_HOME as a pre-requisite of your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JSmooth can actually bundle a JRE with the exe.  What you can do is tell JSmooth where to expect the JRE when running the exe (as in the same folder the exe is run from).  If you do this you simply need to zip the exe and a JRE up, and distribute that.

The end user would unzip this, and the resulting folder would contain your exe and the JRE.  Since JSmooth knows where to look relative your exe, it can find the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

i have use it using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) 
follow the following steps 
1-create project directory called e.g:project 
2-copy the runnable jar file to it 
3-copy the jre directory to it u can rename it or keep name as it e.g i will call myjre

run launch4j program :
1- fill the basic tap with required information .
2- go to JRE tap there is a field called (bundle JRE path ) write "myjre" add min Jar 
virsion 1,6 it will case you an error if you do not fill this fields

and then click run button to generate exe file , you have to remember to keep the myjre directory with along side with executable exe file

e.g the application directory should contains : 
1- [you app name].exe
2-myjre

in this description you can run your application with no care if jre is installed in a machine or not and become portable

Good Luck , feel free to contact me for more details