# I want to create a native app that runs in all OS, and can run terminal commands

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

Can this technology Chrome App or Google NaCl provide me with this capabilities?

Basically it should be able to run terminal commands (even by asking permission first).

And it needs to be able to edit client's filesystem.

I am interested in Chrome App or Google NaCl because they both can run in any operating system (that supports chrome).

Comment: Would you consider other technologies or those two are mandatory?

Comment: Yeah other technologies are fine, are there others?

Comment: Nodejs, python, dart, java, llvm bytecode. Many programming languages of today provide cross arch/os support.

Comment: I need to have GUI working on top of the programming language. NodeJs seem to have TopCube for that but at the moment it is not working on Mac OSX: https://github.com/creationix/topcube

Comment: Java is not preferable since I have to install Java Runtime on my client as I mentioned below. I need something as easy to use as NaCl or Chrome App I think.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95411?hl=en), Chrome is supported on some Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

As your need is not strictly related to Chrome neither a browser, I suggest you to use (or at least have a look at) Java, which is [supported on much more environments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html) any you can safely execute terminal commands. With or without authorization.

Comment: I don't like java because it requires user to install java runtime, which I doubt many of my target users will do. There is a way to wrap on different platforms but it seems there are issues in windows as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330209/whats-the-best-way-to-start-java-applications-on-windows-7 so no, not java I guess... Do you know if NaCl or Chrome App can run terminal commands instead?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome apps cannot execute arbitrary system processes (aka run terminal commands).  There is no permission for this.

Chrome apps can communicate with others apps using message passing, sockets, etc, but you would need a special terminal application to receive these messages -- which would mean first solving the problem you are currently asking to solve!