# Api to read (write) environment variables for chrome apps

Tags: environment-variables, google-chrome-app

Is there an api for [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) that would allow developers to read (and/or write) environment variables?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your specific problem? The answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Chrome Apps are sandboxed, so they shouldn't be able to make those kinds of persistent changes to the system, and they are supposed to be portable across host operating systems, so system-specific concepts like environment variables are generally unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no.

There is another question that is perhaps a little relevant: [I want to create a native app that runs in all OS, and can run terminal commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352113/i-want-to-create-a-native-app-that-runs-in-all-os-and-can-run-terminal-commands/22366464)