# How to make a JWS application pinnable to the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, java-web-start, taskbar

I'm deploying applications using Java Web Start.

To my surprise, one can pin programs to the taskbar in Windows 7, however to my understanding this is only possible if the process in which the program runs is the same than the one that is behind the taskbar icon.

With a JWS application, that's not the case so the application can not be pinned to the taskbar, as shown in the following example:

[image: taskbar screenshot example]

The "u" is my application shortcut, pinned (from the start menu). The other (ugly) icon is the actual application, ran in another process, creating another icon which cannot be pinned. I only get the "Close window" option.

Would it be possible to have a pinnable JWS application?

Comment: potentially a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834599/pinning-a-java-application-to-the-windows-7-taskbar

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanuki Software. Didn't find it in the first place because it's not related to JWS.

Comment: I followed the instructions and successfully called `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`, however the issue is still there: can't pin the application to the taskbar

Comment: It works from either the desktop shortcut (I just checked it) or the start menu item (as you mentioned).  Why the deep urge to also support directly pinning the app. when it is running?

Comment: The shortcut points to javaws.exe (from system folder and not JRE\bin), mentions the JNLP URL and starts the app with other options. It's the shortcut created by JWS with the `<shortcut />` tag in the JNLP file. Are you talking about this one aswell? As for your second question: I'm trying to make this app behave completely like a native one, saving costs using the easy JWS protocol. Making this app look like a native one in Windows 7 comes with a pinnable icon, in my opinon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Did you confirmed this worked with JWS? If so, would you mind sharing your code and JNLP? Thanks.

Comment: *"Did you confirmed this worked with JWS?"*  For the desktop shortcut?  Yes.  *"..would you mind sharing your code and JNLP?"*  I used the icon created by [this demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps) so I suppose that answer is 'no, not at all'.  ;)

Comment: If you are referring to the _PersistenceService demo_ (`persistserv.jnlp`), it creates an application called "JotPad" that cannot be pinned to the taskbar, on my setup.