# Adding items to a pinned program on Windows taskbar (with java) known as JumpList

Tags: java, windows, taskbar, jump-list

Many application when pinned to the taskbar have a popup menu with various menu items. My Java application wrapped with Winrun4j only contains two menu items, one to start the program, and one to remove the item from the taskbar.

How do you add more items to the menu and can it be done within Java 7 ?

Comment: Like this ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html , no idea how it wraps with Winrun4j though. Should work fine if I recall last time I used it.

Comment: This could help you along: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834599/pinning-a-java-application-to-the-windows-7-taskbar

Comment: @Rayf no, thanks I have already tried that but that is the system tray whihc is usually hidden and hence not that useful, I mean the application icon itself pinned to the taskbar

Comment: @DylanMeeus thanks , first of all I thought not as with winrun4j instead of launch4j the application is pinned properly to the taskbar, but answer mentioned this lib http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/#jump_list and it sounds like Im talking about Jump lists, and it looks to provides a solution. But it is rather expensive I wonder if there is an open source alternative