# How to pin my SWT app in the windows taskbar

Tags: java, windows, swt, taskbar

The title pretty much says everything.

I have the icon in the taskbar but when I right click it i can only "close the window".

It might have something to do with [AppUserModelID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330939/pinning-advertised-shortcuts-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-7) , which is related to my first line of code when the program starts : `Display.setAppName("MYAPPNAME");`
I'm aware that there is a TaskBar class which I already use for progress / icon edit / menu ([not working on Win](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fpackage-summary.html)) but there's nothing about pining.

edit : I use launch4j to launch my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only executables can be pinned to the taskbar. A jar file is per se no executable. You can do the following to pin your application:

1. Use a tool like install4j to create an installer and executable of your application
2. Use the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/257467/windows-7-how-to-pin-a-jar-to-the-taskbar)

If you're running it directly from an IDE, there is no way (that I know of) to pin it.

Comment: I forgot to say that i actually use launch4j to launch my program and still can't pin it