# Hide console when running shortcut pinned to taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar, lnk

I'm trying to create a shortcut (`.lnk`) file that will launch [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) without showing the console window, but I need to be able to pin it to the taskbar and have the window and shortcut merge. Scrcpy is bundled with a vbs script that launches scrcpy through wscript, hiding the console, but when I made a shortcut opening that through wscript that made a duplicate window (icon?). I also found a somewhat promising question here about [Pinning advertised shortcuts on the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330939/pinning-advertised-shortcuts-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-7), which led me to an MS Docs page about [AppUserModelIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids), the only problem being I don't really understand how they work, or how to make a shortcut with them.
[image: 1]

Comment: Please can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73353995/edit) your question and add the vbscript code ?

Comment: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/2159

Comment: @rom1v And where is the vbscript code ???? `scrcpy-noconsole.vbs` ????

Comment: In the scrcpy release archive for Windows (and also in the git repo).